# Git code on server

Tags: php, git

I have one private repository at Bitbucket that I use to push my php code.
I would like to know if the best to have the code in my server Amazon EC2.

I cloned the repository on my server and update the code using 'git pull'.

There is a better way to do that?

Comment: My Mysql password is different local and on the server, then every time I have problems with git pull (because changed file) and end up having to reconfigure the git.

Comment: Why not set some conditional logic up in a conf.inc.php which determines what server to connect to and thus selects the right MySQL password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at capistrano or even some deploy building software.  http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html

You do not have to be using ruby to deploy with capistrano